# Cannot stub non-existent property "create" of a mongoose document

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, sinon

I'm writing unit tests for my express app using Sinon. I have a `Log` model:

```js
import { Schema, model } from 'mongoose';

const LogSchema = new Schema({
    content: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },

    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
    },
});

const Log = model('Log', LogSchema);

export default Log;
```

And a `LogController`:

```js
import Log from '../models/Log';

class LogController {
    static async create(content) {
        await Log.create({ content });
    }
}

export default LogController;
```

I'm trying to write tests for `LogController.create()`.

```js
import { createSandbox } from 'sinon';
import Log from '../../../src/models/Log';
import LogController from '../../../src/controllers/LogController';

describe('LogController', () => {
    let sandbox;
    let createStub;

    beforeEach(() => {
        sandbox = createSandbox();

        createStub = sandbox.stub(Log, 'create');
    });

    describe('create()', () => {
        it('should create a Log with the given content', async () => {
            await LogController.create('Bob Lob Law is on the house');

            expect(createStub.calledWith({ content: 'Bob Lob Law is on the house' })).to.be.true;
        });
    });
```

But then I get `TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent property create`, implying that `Log` doesn't have a `create` method. Which is weird, since I have other controllers that are tested exactly like this and they don't throw any error. I also tried stubbing it with `Log.create = sandbox.stub()` but I got the same error. Maybe I'm doing something wrong on my model definition? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Sinon thinks you're trying to stub object.create for some reason (instead of model.create) possibly because model.create returns a promise, but your stub doesn't return anything.  You need to change

```
createStub = sandbox.stub(Log, 'create');
```

to

```
createStub = sandbox.stub(Log, 'create').resolves();
```